# How to make the following scala code faster?

Tags: performance, scala

I am using the using the following scala code in my program. It is being used in a loop. The loop is running for 117x9636 = 1127412 times. It taking a lot of time. And with each loop, the execution time of the following code is increasing.

```
// These lists contain actual values in the actual program
// I am just using empty list in this example for you to understand the data type of these variables
val leftValues: List[Int] = List[Int]() 
val rightValues: List[Int] = List[Int]()
val prevList: List[List[Int]] = List[List[Int]]()

// This is the actual code that is taking so much time
var newList: List[List[Int]] = List[List[Int]]()
newList = prevList :+ (leftValues ++ List.fill(rightValues.size)(""))
```

Can this piece of code be made into something faster? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: see also http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html -> appending to a `List` is O(n).

Comment: Thanks, looking into it.

Comment: Consider immutable `val newList`.

Comment: maybe consider Vector? no idea what you are doing with this list later